# ClassNotFoundException ofbiz

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, ofbiz

I am trying to initialize OfbizWorkflow,but when i try to do that it gives me an error

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericTransactionException
```

as i searched but not unable to find out the dependency. 
Tell me if you have any idea about this dependency

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've just answered your own question below - it's not referenced in your POM. This is basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a dependency is not in the [central repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cofbiz), you can add the downloaded jar manually to your local .m2 repository using the [install-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) goal.

Answer (score 1):

Download apache ofbiz jar from here: http://ofbiz.apache.org/download.html

Comment: does it even have dependency so that i can just add it in the pom.